# How do I Use custom tags for RSS feeder using php

Tags: php, xml, rss

I am trying to build a RSS feed that i would like to have custom tags and not the regular tags like title,description etc. also I want this feed to be validated as true as per w3c standards. can any one help me out ? I am not a regular programmer , a part time programmer. I searched this on net , and came up with suggestions like using a namespace , but can I make my own namespace ? If not what will be the possible solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you start adding custom tags then it won't be standard (by definition) and user agents expecting RSS will not understand your tags (which could cause issues).

(Not that RSS or Atom are W3C specifications, although [Atom is on the IETF standards track](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4287.txt)).

Namespaces will let you create elements without the risk of the colliding with someone else's elements that happen to have the same name.

You can write your own schema to validate against ([IBM have an old introduction](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/xml-schema/)), and that schema can reference elements from multiple namespaces (allowing you to use standard RSS or Atom elements along side your custom ones, hopefully standard user agents should just ignore the unrecognised elements (although not their content)).

Comment: so , it would not validate as true if I use the custom schema also would this be problem at receiver end(as you were saying, i mean would that create problem if I am using yahoo service to fetch these rss feeds of mine) ?

Comment: That is covered in the last paragraph of my answer.